# Comparing time using PHP

Tags: php

I want to create an attendance system, in which the attendance based on following condition:

```
// Conditions
define('LATE_COND', '1306566960'); // strtotime(date('09:16:00'))
define('HALF_COND', '1306576860'); // strtotime(date('09:16:00'))  
define('LATE_CODE', '#FC9E4B');
define('HALF_CODE', '#CCFF33');
define('PRESENT', 'PRESENT');
define('LATE', 'LATE');
define('HALF', 'HALF');

$time_in = strtotime(date('h:i:s'));
if($time_in <= LATE_COND){
$day_status = PRESENT;
$color_code = PRESENT_CODE;
}elseif( ($time_in >= LATE_COND) && ($attendance < HALF_COND) ){
$day_status = LATE;
$color_code = LATE_CODE;
}elseif($time_in >= HALF_COND){
$day_status = HALF;
$color_code = HALF_CODE;
}
```

but for strtotime(date('01:00:00')) value is '1306537200' and hence my all condition failed,
any help and I want to do it using PHP5.x not mysql

Comment: Since 1306537200 <= 1306566960 (late_cond) the first if-statement should match. Makes sense too, because 01:00 today is before 09:16 today. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` return epoch time. Which, if you don't already know, is the number of seconds passed since 1970. Now since you seem to be missing the date, as you are including only time, you can include date in it. `date('Y-m-d h:i:s')`. Hope it helps.

Comment: no it does not work same issue returns 1306543350 for 3:45:xx which is still less than for strtotime(date('Y-m-d 09:16:00'));

Comment: Try full times. I mean `15:45:xx` instead of `3:45:xx`.

Comment: But my bro for Pakistan we have no choice except to use date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Riyadh');
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$twoHrs = strtotime("+2 hours");
echo $time = date('H:i:s a', $twoHrs);
and this always output 03:45:xx for 15:45:xx